# python: get number without decimal places

Tags: python

```
a=123.45324
```

is there a function that will return just `123`?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

[`int`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#int) will always truncate towards zero:

```
>>> a = 123.456
>>> int(a)
123
>>> a = 0.9999
>>> int(a)
0
>>> int(-1.5)
-1
```

The difference between `int` and [`math.floor`](http://docs.python.org/library/math.html#math.floor) is that `math.floor` returns the number as a float, and does not truncate towards zero.

Comment: `math.floor` does what it should (truncate towards negative infinity). In Py3k it returns an `int` (thankfully =p)

Answer (score 5):

Python 2.x:

```
import math
int( math.floor( a ) )
```

N.B. Due to complicated reasons involving the handling of floats, the `int` cast is safe.

Python 3.x:

```
import math
math.floor( a )
```

Comment: what is NB, btw  i sent u an email a few days ago, did u get it?

Comment: hehe yep, will reply when I have free time =p. I've commented on Mark's method.

Comment: gotcha, i thought u were saying something in hebrew

Answer (score 4):

```
a = 123.45324
int(a)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `math.trunc()` function:

```
a=10.2345
print(math.trunc(a))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want both the decimal and non-decimal part:

```py
def split_at_decimal(num):
    integer, decimal = (int(i) for i in str(num).split(".")) 
    return integer, decimal
```

And then:

```sh
>>> split_at_decimal(num=5.55)
(5, 55)
```